# Find specific attribute inside a list with JavaScript/KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

### 1. The goal

Find an attribute inside a list using JavaScript, KnockoutJS or jQuery.

### 2. The scenario

I have a store application working with KnockoutJS to *dynamize* its UI.

### 3. The problem

Each product available to add to shopping cart of my store has an add button, but it is only available if the product isn't on shopping cart already.

I need to iterate with the shopping cart to discover if each product of my available products list is already on it.

### 4. *A few code ago...*

Each product of my available products to add to list is using this fragment to toggle between the buttons:

```
<!-- ko if: Summary.hasItem($element) -->
    <button class="btn btn-small action remove">
        <i class="icon-minus"></i>
    </button>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: Summary.hasItem($element) -->
    <button class="btn btn-small action add">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see, I'm using the `hasItem()` function to check if the product is already on the shopping cart or not — but I have to implement it, and I need your help to do this.

### 5. What I've already tried

As you can see below, I tried to make a loop to check product by product inside my shopping cart until...

```
self.hasItem = function (element) {
    var $productId = $(element).closest("li").data("productid"),
        products = self.products();

    if (products.length > 0) {
        for (var product in products) {
            if (products[product].id() == $productId) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

... something went wrong! *Continues in the next chapter.*

### 6. Something goes wrong

My brain can not compute the logical, but as I have this loop for each button, it seems that when one runs, the other does not run, or if there is an item in the list, the other does not add.

### 7. Playground

[Play with this!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AycoG)

### 8. I need to ask...

My loop/logic is right?

Comment: `for (var product in products)` does not do what you would think: it does not iterate over the array!. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the for loop only executes for the first product.

You should have something like this:

```
for (var product in products) {
        if (products[product].id() == $productId) {
            return true;
        } 
}
return false;
```

Beside the loop, where you should probably use arrayFirst from ko.utils anyway, there seems to be a problem with the add function.

The ng-click binding provides the DOM event as the second parameter, so you probably want to change the signature of the method add to

```
function(data,event) { 
    var element = event.target;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rcwil

```
self.add = function(model, event) {
    console.log($(event.target));

    var $productId = $(event.target).closest("li").data("productid"),
        $productName = $(event.target).closest("h1");

    self.products.push(new Product($productId, $productName));
};
```

Comment: If I add one product and delete it, the others cannot be add.

Comment: I'm not sure if the product id is set correctly. I'll check in the codepen.

Comment: @lulian Actually I'm not using `click` binding to add. I'm using submit — and there is not an `event.target`.

Comment: @chiefGui in the codepen you linked the click binding was used. If you still have problems you should modify the codepen to match your code exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at this a little differently, instead of calling a "hasItem", you should have something like "isSelected" within your Product object.

Then, you can loop around your Products and say (pseudo-code) if is not "isSelected" then show the add button. When this add button is clicked, then the "isSelected" property of your Product object will be set to true.

Make Knockout JS work with your self-contained objects where possible.

Such as:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Products -->
   <!-- ko if: IsSelected --> // Automatically inherited from parent
    <button class="btn btn-small action remove">
        <i class="icon-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
<-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Hello, @ChrisDixon. Thanks about your idea. Can you give me an example of how to I loop around the Products? I'm confusing at this part.

Comment: Updated my answer to give you an example :)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. But you told me the following: "Make Knockout JS work with your self-contained objects where possible." — How can I do it? I ask this because `Products` isn't child of `SummaryViewModel`. (I feel we are almost there!)

Comment: In your ViewModel, you should have a list of Products. These should be self-contained (IsSelected in Product) and so your list of Products should be an observableArray (so you can do a foreach on them, also). This is the beauty and power of Knockout.

Comment: If the list of Products is my observableArray, then `self.products = ko.observableArray();` is what we are talking about. So, the foreach have to work like this: `<!-- ko foreach: Summary.products -->`, right? Dude, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That's exactly right, yup :) but, call it ko.observableArray([]) so it has a value when it's initialised. No problem at all - the more people using Knockout the better, it's an awesome piece of kit.

Comment: Oh, thank you again, but I found a problem =(. When there are two or more products in the *products list* (not shopping cart), all buttons are changed/affected. Any idea?

Comment: The problem specifically is in the "else" statement of KnockoutJS. I'm using the syntax that you have passed, but and if `isSelected` returns false?

Comment: Hmm, is the IsSelected an observable item within your Product object?

Comment: Yes, Chris, `isAdded` is an observable item within my Product object. See: `self.isAdded = ko.observable(isAdded);`. And about my code, [just click here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EtfCh).

Answer (score 1):

In your case this will work  :

```
self.hasItem = function (element) {
    var $productId = $(element).closest("li").data("productid"),
        products = self.products();

     return ko.utils.arrayFirst(products, function(p){
         return (p.id() == $productId);               
     }) != null;
}
```

[ko.utils.arrayFirst](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) returns the first item that match the given predicate; otherwise null.

Comment: The same problem that happens with the @lulian's solution — when I add something to my list and then I remove it without adding another, the other products can't be added. In other words, the other items are affected.

Comment: Does ko.utils.arrayFirst return a reference to the object, or a new copy of it?